# Why can't I access nested properties but can view the data?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue where I can view the data on console log but can't access the nested properties. I am making a recipe app and should display the information when I click on a specific card. Here is the code for the component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import RecipePage from './RecipePage'
export default function Recipes({dataArray}){

const getName = (chicken) => {
    console.log(chicken);
}

useEffect(() => {
    getName()
}, [])

return(
    <div>
        <div className="recipes-main-page-container">
            <h1>Recipes</h1>
            <p id="recipes-main-page-container-subtitle">Browse the glorious chicken recipes from different cooking styles and cuisines.</p>
            <Link to={{pathname:'/recipepage', state: {idk: {name}}}}>
            <div className="recipes-main-card-container">
                {dataArray.map((item, index) => 
                    dataArray.map((food, index) => 
                        food.map(chicken => 
                        <div key={chicken.idMeal} className="recipes-main-card" onClick={() => getName(chicken)}> 
                            <img src={chicken.strMealThumb} alt="food" />
                                <div className="recipes-main-card-text">
                                    <p>{chicken.strArea}</p>
                                    <h2>{chicken.strMeal}</h2> 
                                </div>
                    </div> )
                    ))}
            </div>
        </Link>
        
    </div>
  
    </div>
    
)
```

}

When I click on a card, it logs out the information in console log like so:

> `Object { idMeal: "52920", strMeal: "Chicken Marengo", strDrinkAlternate: null, strCategory: "Chicken", strArea: "French", strInstructions: "Heat the oil in a large flameproof casserole dish and stir-fry the mushrooms until they start to soften. Add the chicken legs and cook briefly on each side to colour them a little.\r\nPour in the passata, crumble in the stock cube and stir in the olives. Season with black pepper – you shouldn’t need salt. Cover and simmer for 40 mins until the chicken is tender. Sprinkle with parsley and serve with pasta and a salad, or mash and green veg, if you like.", strMealThumb: "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/qpxvuq1511798906.jpg", strTags: null, strYoutube: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U33HYUr-0Fw", strIngredient1: "Olive Oil", … } ​ dateModified: null ​ idMeal: "52920" ​ strArea: "French" ​ strCategory: "Chicken" ​ strCreativeCommonsConfirmed: null ​ strDrinkAlternate: null ​ strImageSource: null ​ strIngredient1: "Olive Oil" ​ strIngredient10: "" ​ strIngredient11: "" ​ strIngredient12: "" ​ strIngredient13: "" ​ strIngredient14: "" ​ strIngredient15: "" ​ strIngredient16: "" ​ strIngredient17: "" ​ strIngredient18: "" ​ strIngredient19: "" ​ strIngredient2: "Mushrooms" ​ strIngredient20: "" ​ strIngredient3: "Chicken Legs" ​ strIngredient4: "Passata" ​ strIngredient5: "Chicken Stock Cube" ​ strIngredient6: "Black Olives" ​ strIngredient7: "Parsley" ​ strIngredient8: "" ​ strIngredient9: "" ​ strInstructions: "Heat the oil in a large flameproof casserole dish and stir-fry the mushrooms until they start to soften. Add the chicken legs and cook briefly on each side to colour them a little.\r\nPour in the passata, crumble in the stock cube and stir in the olives. Season with black pepper – you shouldn’t need salt. Cover and simmer for 40 mins until the chicken is tender. Sprinkle with parsley and serve with pasta and a salad, or mash and green veg, if you like." ​ strMeal: "Chicken Marengo" ​ strMealThumb: "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/qpxvuq1511798906.jpg" ​ strMeasure1: "1 tbs" ​ strMeasure10: "" ​ strMeasure11: "" ​ strMeasure12: "" ​ strMeasure13: "" ​ strMeasure14: "" ​ strMeasure15: "" ​ strMeasure16: "" ​ strMeasure17: "" ​ strMeasure18: "" ​ strMeasure19: "" ​ strMeasure2: "300g" ​ strMeasure20: "" ​ strMeasure3: "4" ​ strMeasure4: "500g" ​ strMeasure5: "1" ​ strMeasure6: "100g " ​ strMeasure7: "Chopped" ​ strMeasure8: "" ​ strMeasure9: "" ​ strSource: "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/3146682/chicken-marengo" ​ strTags: null ​ strYoutube: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U33HYUr-0Fw" ​ <prototype>: Object { … } Recipes.js:10`

When I change it to

```
const getName = (chicken) => {
console.log(chicken.strMeal);
```

}

I receive an error "TypeError: chicken is undefined"

Why can't I access the properties?

Comment: R u sure that error doesnt come from your useEffect? You are not providing any chicken arg.

Comment: I've tried putting 'chicken' in the argument of UseEffect and getName(chicken) inside of the useEffect. Still receiving the error that chicken is undefined

Answer (score 1):

why are you calling `getName()` inside `useEffect`?

what that is doing is, firing off the getName function the minute your component mounts. Now, since you aren't passing any argument into this `getName()` function, when you do a `console.log(chicken)`, chicken is undefined, and your console will print that ( cross check this when your component mounts ).

But when you changed this to `console.log(chicken.strMeal)` what happens is, your component mounts > `getName()` is fired. and chicken has not been passed as an argument (hence `chicken === undefined`), which is why when you try to access `chicken.strMeal` it throws an error.